# Effect of humidity on removing excess charge from objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, water, conductors, insulators

The usual answer to the question "why electrostatic discharge happens more often on dry days" is that water - due to its polarity - has the tendency to remove the excess charge.

But I do not understand how exactly does it happen since water is an insulator, not a conductor. Are electrons from charged objects shuffled from one water molecule to another, until they reach the ground? If they could do so, then pure water would conduct electricity - but it does not. Perhaps individual water molecule collect excess electrons and move away from the object, staying in H2O- state? Or is it because ion-containing water (i.e. minerals, salts and other impurities) condenses on the charged, non-conductive objects and creates a thin layer of conductivity? But the answers usually refer to the conductivity of the air, not the objects in question. Maybe the ions present in the air conduct the electricity? If so, then why question (and answers) refer mostly to the polarity of water?